# Can typedefs in source files cause ODR violations?

Tags: c++, linker, one-definition-rule

I've picked up the habit to always enclose types defined in source files in unnamed namespaces because I know they can cause ODR violations:

```
// my_source.cpp
namespace {
  struct MyStruct {};
}
```

What happens though in a source file that doesn't define a type, but merely aliases an existing one e.g.:

```
// another_source.cpp
using error_t = ::prj::telemetry::ErrorType;
```

could this create an ODR violation or cause weird linker behavior (e.g. discard one of the two types) if some other source contains:

```
// some_other_source.cpp
using errot_t = ::prj::linalg::ErrorType;
```

basically would the same rules applied to type definitions, also apply to typedefs?

Answer (score 3):

No (but actually more nuanced, see below). Typedefs like those in the question cannot cause ODR violations.

Firstly, typedefs ([dcl.typedef](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef) in current standard draft) are usually declarations and not definitions. Even if you declare two typedefs in the form of those in the question in the same TU twice, that is a redeclaration error, and has nothing to do with ODR rule. If you don't have a definition of something, you can't possibly have a ODR violation for it. Note that both forms of `typedef ...` and `using ... = ...` are considered typedefs and fall under [dcl.typedef] in terms of the language specification. The relevant quotes about these typedefs not introducing new types are given [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link/dcl.typedef#1.sentence-6)

> A typedef-name does not introduce a new type the way a class declaration ([class.name]) or enum declaration ([dcl.enum]) does.

and [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link/dcl.typedef#2.sentence-5)

> Such a typedef-name has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the typedef specifier. In particular, it does not define a new type.

Secondly, ODR violation across different TU can only happen with names that have external linkage, or names with module linkage for TUs in the same module. In particular, names with no linkage cannot lead to cross-TU ODR violations. The cases for linkages are covered in [basic.link](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link) from the latest standard draft, and in particular, the typedef declarations in the question falls under [item 7](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#7),

> Names not covered by these rules have no linkage. Moreover, except as noted, a name declared at block scope has no linkage.

Now here comes the more nuanced part. For the literal question in the title, the answer is actually yes, that is because we also have items [4.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#4.3) and [4.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#4.4) about typedefs to unnamed class types and unnamed enums, which introduce the concept of "typedef name used for linkage purposes".

> The name of an entity that belongs to a namespace scope that has not
> been given internal linkage above and that is the name of
>
> ...
>
> - a named class ([class.pre]), or an unnamed class defined in a typedef
>   declaration in which the class has the typedef name for linkage
>   purposes ([dcl.typedef]);
> - a named enumeration, or an unnamed enumeration defined in a typedef
>   declaration in which the enumeration has the typedef name for linkage
>   purposes ([dcl.typedef]);
>
> ...

The actual definition is given in [item 4 of dcl.typedef](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef#4).

> An unnamed class or enumeration C defined in a typedef declaration has
> the first typedef-name declared by the declaration to be of type C as
> its typedef name for linkage purposes ([basic.link]).

That means if we have the following code appearing in two different TUs, we have a ODR violation. And this is technically one form of `typedef` so it falls into the scope of the title of the question.

In the first TU:

```
typedef struct {} S, S1;
```

and in the second TU:

```
typedef struct {int x;} S, S2;
```

Answer (score 2):

A typedef or a using statement does not introduce a new type, it just introduces an alias to another type, so no ODR violation is possible.  From cppreference:

[`typedef`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef)

> The typedef names are aliases for existing types, and are not declarations of new types

[`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

> A type alias declaration introduces a name which can be used as a synonym for the type denoted by type-id. It does not introduce a new type and it cannot change the meaning of an existing type name

Comment: But can such type aliases be mixed up or end up designating the wrong type?

Comment: If you create an alias and name it `bob` and there is already a type named `bob` then when you use `bob` like `bob b;` then you'll get an ambiguity error since it wont know which `bob` to use.

Comment: @LorahAttkins Or it'll give you a nice error that a type with that name already exists: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e1c79e5f114294e, https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ae9724d64cde379

Comment: If there's two types named `bob` that have been defined in different translation units w/o namespace "protection" you open a can of worms even if those two sources don't have visibility/access/inclusion/dependency to each other. Can such a thing happen if two source files simply create an alias having the same name w/o an unnamed namespace ? (I'm not discussing the case where the type is visible to both declarations at all, that's straightforward )

Comment: no, they alias is fine.  And you can have two types names `bob` in two different TU's.  It is only an ODR violation when more than one definition makes it into a TU.

Comment: I'd like to challenge the last point. C++ is not similar to C in this case: each TU can have its own definition (completely blind of the other) and the linker e.g. with LTO enabled can end up discarding or merging the two [like in this example](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/issues/9099#issuecomment-447375873). I've had a case where one TU worked fine while the other produced code that called the wrong destructor (!) w/o the two TU ever talking to each other (or including related headers). The rule to "always define .cpp local types inside an unnamed namespace" remedies exactly this

Comment: @LorahAttkins Yeah, my mistake, can't do that even if they are in separate TU's.  You are still safe with the aliases as no new type is introduced.